# crossbrowser opacity mixin for .less

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, less, phpstorm

I am trying to use Javascript in LESS to be compiled in phpstorm..

I am trying to create a function based off of a cross-browser implementation of opacity found at this site : [link](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)

Specifically, I am trying to create a LESS function to recreate this piece of code:

```
.crossbrowseropacity {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

This is what I have in LESS to achieve it:

```
.crossbrowser(@color,@alpha){
  @myred:red(@color);
  @mygreen:green(@color);
  @myblue:blue(@color);
  @ievalue:Math.floor(@alpha * 255).toString(16);
  background-color: @color;
  background-color: rgba(@myred,@mygreen,@myblue,@alpha);

/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/

  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue, endColorstr=#@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue);

  /* For IE 8*/

  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue, endColorstr=#@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue)";
}
```

It will not compile right..could someone help me with this?

Comment: Any error message that might help someone help debug this?

Comment: It gives a syntax error on line : 12  - where it has @ievalue:Math.floor(@alpha * 255).toString(16);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using LESS 1.3.1 or later, then this does what you want (using built in functions):

**LESS**

```
//define mixin
.crossbrowser(@color,@alpha){
  @rgba: rgba(red(@color),green(@color),blue(@color),@alpha);
  @argb: argb(@rgba);
  background-color: @color;
  background-color: @rgba;
  filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@{argb}, endColorstr=@{argb})";
  -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@{argb}, endColorstr=@{argb})";
}

//use it
.crossbrowser(red, .2);
```

**CSS Output**

```
background-color: #ff0000;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#33ff0000, endColorstr=#33ff0000);
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#33ff0000, endColorstr=#33ff0000);
```

Comment: This, right here, is the right answer.  I've come across this question about the filter property in LESS so many times it hurts. Use the tilde, it allows you to output multiple variables in what would otherwise be interpreted as part of a larger algorithm.

Comment: @JoshBurgess: Part of his other issue was obviously building the  `#AARRGGBB` for the `filter` properties, but the latest LESS accommodates that with the `argb()` function.

Comment: This works, any way to change the title of this post so perhaps someone searching could find it easier? Something like crossbrowser opacity LESS mixin ?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if the progid:DXImage... after -ms-filter isn't surrounded by qoutations? " "  The example from the site shows it but it seems to work in IE8 without them(which your less function produces)

Comment: @CI_Guy: If you wanted quotes, you can add single quotes inside the double quotes, but I agree, I'm not certain it is completely necessary.

Comment: @CI_Guy: You should be able to edit the post and in doing so be able to edit the title to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation):

> However, if you still want to use JavaScript in .less, this is done by wrapping the expression with back-ticks:

```
@var: `"hello".toUpperCase() + '!'`;
```

So your line should be this (I think):

```
@ievalue:`Math.floor(@alpha * 255).toString(16)`;
```

And since you're using a variable inside, you might need to use [string interpolation](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation), but then again, you might not, because your @alpha isn't inside a string. If that doesn't work, give this a try:

```
@ievalue:`Math.floor(@{alpha} * 255).toString(16)`;
```

*That one looks funny, I think it's wrong. Hopefully the first one works. But it looks like you will need to use interpolation where you later do this:*

```
"...#@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue..."
```

*Because you are inside a string on the last line of your example code, I think that should be:*

```
"...#@{ievalue}+@{myred}+@{mygreen}+@{myblue}..."
```

As for your latest question, you probably need to use this other bit called Escaping:

> **[Escaping](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping)**
>
> Sometimes you might need to output a CSS value which is either not valid CSS syntax, or uses proprietary syntax which LESS doesn’t recognize.
>
> To output such value, we place it inside a string prefixed with ~, for example:

```
.class {
  filter: ~"ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff()";
}
```

So your last two lines should probably be this:

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#@{ievalue}+@{myred}+@{mygreen}+@{myblue}, endColorstr=#@{ievalue}+@{myred}+@{mygreen}+@{myblue})";

/* For IE 8*/

-ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#@{ievalue}+@{myred}+@{mygreen}+@{myblue}, endColorstr=#@{ievalue}+@{myred}+@{mygreen}+@{myblue})";
```

I found [this very brief example](http://www.thebrightlines.com/2011/11/25/filter-styles-in-less/) to back it up, but again, I haven't tried it.

Comment: I don't get compile error any more for : @ievalue:`Math.floor(@alpha * 255).toString(16)`; But I still get error for the filter and -ms-filter lines trying both of your examples

Comment: I've tried your exact examples as well as   -ms-filter: ~"'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#"@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue~''", endColorstr=#"@ievalue+@myred+@mygreen+@myblue ~")"; and still have compile issues :(

Comment: from that example.. this does work -ms-filter: ~"'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=" @alpha*100 ~")'";               I'll try messing with this

Comment: None of the above worked so I have added a bounty.. this would be a nice function to have for quick IE opacity conversions from a hex value color